# Update Query not updating entity values Room

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room

Room , Mvvm Created , Kotlin - Add , Delete are working 
but when i run update nothing changes

i had debugged the app , dao , repo and viewModel class are showing the changes but no changes reflect on my recyclerView or when i destroy and again open my app it does not changes

My Model/Entity Classs :

```
data class IceBreakerModel(val question:String,
                           val date:String,
                           val option1:String,
                           val option2:String,
                           val option3:String){
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0
}
```

Dao : -

```
interface IcebreakerDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertQuestion(question:IceBreakerModel)

    @Query("DELETE FROM ice_breaker_questions WHERE id=:ID")
    fun deleteQuestion(ID:Int)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM ice_breaker_questions")
    fun getAllIcebreakerQuestions():LiveData<List<IceBreakerModel>>

    @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun updateIcebreakerQuestion(question:IceBreakerModel)

//    @Query("UPDATE ice_breaker_questions SET  question =:newQuestion ,date=:newDate,option1=:newOption1,option2=:newOption2,option3=:newOption3 WHERE id=:ID")
//    fun updateQuestion(newQuestion:String,newDate:String,newOption1:String,newOption2:String,newOption3:String,ID:Int)
}
```

Repo :-

```
    private class UpdateQuestion(dao:IcebreakerDao):AsyncTask<IceBreakerModel,Unit,Unit>(){
        val questionDao = dao
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: IceBreakerModel?) {
            val model = params[0]!!
            questionDao.updateIcebreakerQuestion(model)
//            questionDao.updateQuestion(model.question,model.date,model.option1,model.option2,model.option3,model.id)
        }
    }
```

and Finally Main Activity where i am updating

```
iceBreakerViewModel.updateQuestion(IceBreakerModel(question,Date().toString(),option1,option2,option3))
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: You are using @Update query in DAO and calling updateQuestion() function from view. Please correct that and try again.

Comment: @PRERNAGUPTA please check again , i am calling updateQuestion from my viewModel where i already have .  fun updateQuestion(question:IceBreakerModel){
        repository.updateQuestion(question)
    }

Answer (score 1):

The method you commented:

```
@Query("UPDATE ice_breaker_questions SET  question =:newQuestion ,date=:newDate,option1=:newOption1,option2=:newOption2,option3=:newOption3 WHERE id=:ID")
fun updateQuestion(newQuestion:String,newDate:String,newOption1:String,newOption2:String,newOption3:String,ID:Int)
```

Is the way to go. At least it's how I'm used to update my columns.

Also, I think you need to `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` inside the observer of the ViewModel in your activity and in your ViewModel, assuming you are using LiveData.

Let me know if you need anything else, as I might missed the point somewhere

Comment: yep , but i can't use id cz then i need to send id from my mainActivity by check in my entity class id is not in public constructor ! its in private

Comment: I simulated your model and you can do " model.id " to get your ID. I just tried it. 

Did you change your model by doing " private var id: Int=0 "?

Comment: here is my model/Entity data class IceBreakerModel(val question:String,
                           val date:String,
                           val option1:String,
                           val option2:String,
                           val option3:String){
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0
}

Comment: however i changed my model now , and took the id inside public constructor , and when adding i am adding (0..100).random() for id ,and it is updating now but is this a good approach?

Comment: I don't think so, because there's a chance that that random generates an ID equal to an ID that you already have, replacing the existing question, something that I think you don't want. It's weird that you can't access id. Look here https://prnt.sc/p2kjqf 

No errors whatsoever

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help!